# WGET: download only files

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

I want to download  some .dat files using `wget`. The files are downloaded properly, however, it comes a lot of folders and index.html as well.
My question is: Can I download only the .dat files?

I wrote the following command: `wget dat -r --user=mymail@myprovider.com --password=passwd http://site-example/ftp/data/2015-01/2015-01-27/2015-01-27_1315.dat`

Comment: That suggests you did something else than "download .dat files". Can you include the command line you used in your post?

Comment: @Jongware ok, I'm going to update the post

Comment: @Jongware I meant, wget writes all site contents to my pc, including folders and subfolders. What I want is download only the .dat files on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I added --no parent and it downloaded only the selected folder.